# connect to sFTP server while using Xcode

Tags: xcode5, sftp

I wonder how to access scripts on a sFTP server when using Xcode.
I want to write the code using Xcode and update it on the server simultaneously every time I save the code. 
There is similar function in TextWrangular, where you can "open from sFTP/FTP server".
I try to add server in Xcode, I choose Preferences->Accounts-> Add Server, but when I enter the server address and my user name, it says could not connect to the server. I wonder if this is possible using Xcode or what I've done wrong!

Thank you very much!!!